# Application gives an Render error when using react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I tried to create a basic table using React table package. But It gives a render error.

Here is a link to the approach I tried
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-example-nbmti?file=/src/Talbe.tsx

I was referring to this example while creating the table
https://codesandbox.io/s/997mn?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shared sandbox link (i.e. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-example-nbmti?file=/src/Talbe.tsx), on Line number 50, the argument passed to `cell.render` method is **"cell"**. Its casing is incorrect. It should be **"Cell"** instead.

```
<td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
```

Refer Line number 72 in the reference link that has been shared (i.e. https://codesandbox.io/s/997mn?file=/src/index.tsx)